# How to stop Google Chrome from restructuring long arrays?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I'm currently using Chrome's Developer Tools to create an array which contains every word in the Scrabble dictionary, which I can then use in my Scrabble predictor program. The dictionary can be found here: http://scrabblehelper.googlecode.com/svn-history/r20/trunk/ScrabbleHelper/src/dictionaries/sowpods.txt

So far, I've built a jQuery scraper which produces an array of 267,752 words. The code is simply:

```
var allWords = $('pre').innerText;
allWords = allWords.split('\n');
```

I hoped this might create a straightforward array which I could then copy straight into my program. However, instead, it structures the array - breaking it down into sections of [0-99], [100-199], which I can't simply copy over. Does anyone know how to stop Chrome from doing this, so that `allWords` simply becomes an array in the format `["AARDVARK", "AARDWOLF", "ABACUS", ... ]` and so on?

When I simply copy the `console.log` output, I get the following mess:

```
Array[267752][0 … 9999][0 … 99]0: "AA"1: "AAH"2: "AAHED"3: "AAHING"4: "AAHS"5: "AAL"6: "AALII"7: "AALIIS"8: "AALS"9: "AARDVARK"10: "AARDVARKS"11: "AARDWOLF"12: "AARDWOLVES"13: "AARGH"14: "AARRGH"15: "AARRGHH"16: "AARTI"17: "AARTIS"18: "AAS"19: "AASVOGEL"20: "AASVOGELS"21: "AB"22: "ABA"23: "ABAC"24: "ABACA"25: "ABACAS"26: "ABACI"27: "ABACK"28: "ABACS"29: "ABACTERIAL"30: "ABACTINAL"31: "ABACTINALLY"32: "ABACTOR"33: "ABACTORS"34: "ABACUS"35: "ABACUSES"36: "ABAFT"37: "ABAKA"38: "ABAKAS"39: "ABALONE"40: "ABALONES"41: "ABAMP"42: "ABAMPERE"43: "ABAMPERES"44: "ABAMPS"45: "ABAND"46: "ABANDED"47: "ABANDING"48: "ABANDON"49: "ABANDONED"50: "ABANDONEDLY"51: "ABANDONEE"52: "ABANDONEES"53: "ABANDONER"54: "ABANDONERS"55: "ABANDONING"56: "ABANDONMENT"57: "ABANDONMENTS"58: "ABANDONS"59: "ABANDONWARE"60: "ABANDONWARES"61: "ABANDS"62: "ABAPICAL"63: "ABAS"64: "ABASE"65: "ABASED"66: "ABASEDLY"67: "ABASEMENT"68: "ABASEMENTS"69: "ABASER"70: "ABASERS"71: "ABASES"72: "ABASH"73: "ABASHED"74: "ABASHEDLY"75: "ABASHES"76: "ABASHING"77: "ABASHLESS"78: "ABASHMENT"79: "ABASHMENTS"80: "ABASIA"81: "ABASIAS"82: "ABASING"83: "ABASK"84: "ABATABLE"85: "ABATE"86: "ABATED"87: "ABATEMENT"88: "ABATEMENTS"89: "ABATER"90: "ABATERS"91: "ABATES"92: "ABATING"93: "ABATIS"94: "ABATISES"95: "ABATOR"96: "ABATORS"97: "ABATTIS"98: "ABATTISES"99: "ABATTOIR"[100 … 199][200 … 299][300 … 399][400 … 499][500 … 599][600 … 699][700 … 799][800 … 899][900 … 999][1000 … 1099][1100 … 1199][1200 … 1299][1300 … 1399][1400 … 1499][1500 … 1599][1600 … 1699][1700 … 1799][1800 … 1899][1900 … 1999][2000 … 2099][2100 … 2199][2200 … 2299][2300 … 2399][2400 … 2499][2500 … 2599][2600 … 2699][2700 … 2799][2800 … 2899][2900 … 2999][3000 … 3099][3100 … 3199][3200 … 3299][3300 … 3399][3400 … 3499][3500 … 3599][3600 … 3699][3700 … 3799][3800 … 3899][3900 … 3999][4000 … 4099][4100 … 4199][4200 … 4299][4300 … 4399][4400 … 4499][4500 … 4599][4600 … 4699][4700 … 4799][4800 … 4899][4900 … 4999][5000 … 5099][5100 … 5199][5200 … 5299][5300 … 5399][5400 … 5499][5500 … 5599][5600 … 5699][5700 … 5799][5800 … 5899][5900 … 5999][6000 … 6099][6100 … 6199][6200 … 6299][6300 … 6399][6400 … 6499][6500 … 6599][6600 … 6699][6700 … 6799][6800 … 6899][6900 … 6999][7000 … 7099][7100 … 7199][7200 … 7299][7300 … 7399][7400 … 7499][7500 … 7599][7600 … 7699][7700 … 7799][7800 … 7899][7900 … 7999][8000 … 8099][8100 … 8199][8200 … 8299][8300 … 8399][8400 … 8499][8500 … 8599][8600 … 8699][8700 … 8799][8800 … 8899][8900 … 8999][9000 … 9099][9100 … 9199][9200 … 9299][9300 … 9399][9400 … 9499][9500 … 9599][9600 … 9699][9700 … 9799][9800 … 9899][9900 … 9999][10000 … 19999][20000 … 29999][30000 … 39999][40000 … 49999][50000 … 59999][60000 … 69999][70000 … 79999][80000 … 89999][90000 … 99999][100000 … 109999][110000 … 119999][120000 … 129999][130000 … 139999][140000 … 149999][150000 … 159999][160000 … 169999][170000 … 179999][180000 … 189999][190000 … 199999][200000 … 209999][210000 … 219999][220000 … 229999][230000 … 239999][240000 … 249999][250000 … 259999][260000 … 267751]length: 267752__proto__: Array[0]
```

Comment: Huh, what do you mean by “sections”?

Comment: what do you want to copy? the `console.log` output? devTools are just "breaking it down" for visual purposes. it's still a normal array.

Comment: @Kryptik Working on this now. My computer's rather slow at the moment though...

Comment: @Kryptik Yes, I'm trying to copy the console.log output.

Answer (score 3):

It's not breaking it down into anything. It's just a normal array.

The developer tools chunk them in pieces to make it easier for you to read visually.

```
var allWords = $('pre').innerText;
allWords = allWords.split('\n');
allWords.length == some really big number
```

Comment: I get this when I copy it though...

Array[267752][0 … 9999][0 … 99]0: "AA"1: "AAH"2: "AAHED"3: "AAHING"4: "AAHS"5: "AAL"6: "AALII"7: "AALIIS"8: "AALS"9: "AARDVARK"10: "AARDVARKS"11: "AARDWOLF"12: "AARDWOLVES"13: "AARGH"14: "AARRGH"15: "AARRGHH"16: "AARTI"17: "AARTIS"18: "AAS"19: "AASVOGEL"20: "AASVOGELS"21:

Comment: Copy it how? I assure you, Chrome is not changing the underlying data structure of your array that you're creating with `.split()`. If it did, many, many things would be breaking.

Comment: I'm copying it from the console. Do you know any better way of doing this?

Comment: @Zetland - You are using javascript application to fetch data - since you already have the code done, how about using `nw.js` to create an application which can save the data you obtained into a file or even a database? `nw` is basically a version of Chrome with lower security settings, so it can write to your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, really. Chrome's dev tools is splitting the array up into chunks because generally when you're debugging it's more helpful to look only at a chunk than the whole thing.

You can use `console.log(allWords.join(","))` if you simply want to see a comma-separated list of all the words.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just run JSON.stringify() on your array, and copy the resulting string? Alternatively, you could use a script to insert the value of the array into an element on the page, and copy from that.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `copy` command from the [console API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/command-line/command-line-reference?hl=en#copyobject). Combine it with the recommendation of `JSON.stringify` to get a string representation of the array.

For example:

`copy(JSON.stringify(document.querySelector('pre').innerText.split('\n')))`

This will copy the contents directly to the clipboard, no fussing with manually copying it in any way.

Note: This is only available in the console. To do it from the web page, you will need something like [clipboard.js](https://zenorocha.github.io/clipboard.js/). You can use the underlying technology using execCommand and selection APIs, but clipboard makes it so easy without much overhead.