# Accessing second layer of array in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to access an array from an S3 file which I have created the backend route for. I just can't seem to access the array on the front end.

So, my API request using my s3 bucket is:

```
router.get('/apollo/keywords', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let apolloK = await dataFromS3(s3Bucket, apolloKeywords);
    res.json(apolloK);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  }
});
```

On the front end, I've created a keyword item component:

```
const KeywordItem = (props) => {

    const { keyword } = props.keyword;

    return (
      <div className='card text-center'>
        <h4>{keyword}</h4>
        <button>Delete</button>
      </div>
    )

}

export default KeywordItem;
```

which then gets fed to a Keyword Component:

```
class Keywords extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={userStyle}>
        {this.props.keywords.map((keyword, index) => (
          <KeywordItem key={index} keyword={keyword} />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const userStyle = {
  display: 'grid',
  gridTemplateColumns: 'repeat(3, 1fr)',
  gridGap: '1rem'
}

export default Keywords;
```

And I try to access the data in the main app.js file with axios:

```
class App extends Component {

  state = {
    keywords: [],
    loading: false
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/keywords/apollo/keywords');
    console.log(res);
    this.setState({ keywords: res.data[0], loading: false });   
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Keywords loading={this.state.loading} keywords={this.state.keywords} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

With this code, the page displays cards full of empty information and a delete button, because after looking into what I was actually pulling it was the array itself without getting the individual values. The array I'm calling looks like this:

```
{data: Array(1), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
data: Array(1)
0: Array(297)
[0 … 99]
[100 … 199]
[200 … 296]
length: 297
__proto__: Array(0)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
status: 200
statusText: "OK"
headers: {content-length: "5423", content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
config: {url: "http://localhost:5000/keywords/apollo/keywords", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentia
```

How can I access those elements [0-99]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop Google Chrome from restructuring long arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34070739/how-to-stop-google-chrome-from-restructuring-long-arrays)

Comment: componentDidMount should not be async. You should really take a look at functional components, many of these classes could be written with less hazzle - `const { keyword } = props.keyword;` do you set the prop `keyword` with an object holding a prop `keyword`?

Comment: Are you loading the array into another array? If so, the array you want to target would be at this.state.keywords[0]. So, each keyword would be keywords[0][0], keywords[0][1], keywords[0][2], etc.

Comment: Hi Brian - Thanks for the link but I nothing seemed to work. 
Julian - I actually learned functional components in greater detail before I learned how to do it with class components so this is an attempt to understand how it's done this way. I think what I tried to do with that particular props was to destructure it but it's really not necessary as it's only one...and Dave I'm not loading it into another array intentionally, but it seems to be doing it when I create the array after splitting the text file that's on AWS S3. I tried accessing it with [0][0] but got a TypeError.